# Widgetset Error after Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8 Migration

Tags: java, maven, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

i converted the Project from Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8 using compatibility in the pom.xml

I had in my UI

```
@Widgetset("com.example.widgetset.MyWidgetset")
```

in my Servlet

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyUI.class,widgetset = "com.example.widgetset.MyWidgetset"
```

and in the MyWidgetset

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet" />
```

Now if i compile the Widgetset i get this Error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.9.4:compile (default-cli) on project Example: GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
```

What is wrong on this settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet` is additional widgetset that contains Vaadin 7 compatibility widgets for Vaadin 8. This is not included in standard client jars. You are probably missing `vaadin-compatibility-client` or `vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled` in your project.